# Two Library folders in Mac

Tags: mac, storage, macos

I'm cleaning up my MBP and found two Library folders, one of 3.37 Gb and the other 9.75 Gb. Why are there two of them, and more importantly, how can I reduce their sizes?

[image]

[image]